# “for” loop to get status of the service in bash script

Tags: bash

I have a bash script where it will start the service and checks for the status of the service. But when I start the service the application will take 15 seconds to change the service status from "No" to "Yes" and my bash script returns status as "No" because it checks the status immediately after I start the service. So, I want a "for" loop for my bash script where it should checks for the status for every 1 second and breaks the for loop once it gets the status as "Yes" and should exit after 15 seconds.

```
app_start=`/usr/bin/AppStart.py`
app_status=`/usr/bin/AppStatus.py | grep -oPm1 "(?<=<Status>)[^<]+"`
 if [[ $app_status = "Yes" ]] ; then
 echo "Yes"
 else
 echo "No"
 fi
```

The above command in my bash script will return the status immediately after I start the service.

Comment: So code that? Where is the problem? Study a good introduction into bash and shell programming and writing such loop will be trivial. Remember to check your scripts with http://shellcheck.net - backticks \` are discouraged, use `$(...)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me give you some pseudo-code for solving your issue:

```
boolean bFinish = false
integer iSeconds = 0

while (NOT(bFinish) AND (iSeconds < 15)) {
  bFinish = check_if_app_status_is_Yes(...)
  iSeconds = iSeconds + 1
  sleep 1
}
```

For your information: `sleep <x>` is the correct UNIX/Linux command for pauzing the execution for `<x>` seconds.